# Twilio Function Code - Call Forwarding Depending On Date/Time

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am trying to create a scheduled call forwarding function in Twilio where if its Saturday between 8-3, it will forward the call to a different number. Below is the code im using (created in chatGPT).

I have basic coding experience and it looks ok to me however it doesn't actually work, im sure im missing something simple (I have replaced my actual number with XXX for privacy).

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const timezoneOffset = 0; // GMT timezone offset in hours
  const divertPhoneNumber = '+44XXXXXXXXXX'; // Phone number to divert the call to during specified hours
  const fallbackPhoneNumber = '+44XXXXXXXXXX'; // Phone number to connect the call to outside of specified hours
  const currentDatetime = new Date();
  const currentDay = currentDatetime.getUTCDay();
  const currentHour = currentDatetime.getUTCHours() + timezoneOffset;

  if (currentDay === 6 && currentHour >= 8 && currentHour < 15) {
    const twiml = `
      <Response>
        <Dial>${divertPhoneNumber}</Dial>
      </Response>
    `;
    callback(null, twiml);
  } else {
    const twiml = `
      <Response>
        <Dial>${fallbackPhoneNumber}</Dial>
      </Response>
    `;
    callback(null, twiml);
  }
};
```

Have tried creating a function in Twilio, deploying it to public and then pointing my studio flow to this specific function.

Comment: Can you describe what is and what isn't working? Is it always calling the same number or do you see execution errors in the console?

Comment: No error in the console unfortunately. The call just cuts off, nothing rings

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

To forward incoming calls based on the date and time, you can use Twilio's [Dial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) verb in TwiML. Here's the updated code snippet for forwarding calls to a specific phone number:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    const currentDatetime = new Date();
    const currentDay = currentDatetime.getUTCDay();
    const currentHour = currentDatetime.getUTCHours();

    const phoneNumber = "<Phone_Number>";

    // Check if it's Saturday between 8-15 UTC
    const isSaturday = currentDay === 6;
    const isWithinHours = currentHour >= 8 && currentHour < 15;

    // Generate the TwiML to tell Twilio how to forward the call
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    if (isSaturday && isWithinHours) {
        twiml.dial(phoneNumber);
    } else {
        twiml.say('Sorry, we are currently unavailable. Please try again on Saturday between 8-15 UTC.');
    }

    // Return the TwiML
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

You can also refer to this [example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/time-of-day-routing) in the Twilio Function to implement call forwarding based on day and time using Twilio Studio.

For a simple call forwarding setup with Function, you can utilise our partner's [App](https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange/simple-call-forwarding) available on the Code Exchange platform.

Please give it a try and let me know how it works for you.